# Append two strings as a single element to a Python list

Tags: list, python-2.7, append, element

I want to append two strings as a single element to a Python list. This is a simplified example of my problem:

```
lowerCase = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
newList = []

# Append two pieces of data as a single element
i = 1;
for letter in lowerCase[0]:
    [newList.append(letter), newList.append(i)]
    i += 1

print newList
print len(newList)
```

What I get:

```
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4, 'e', 5]
10
```

What I want:

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5]]
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `for` loop. It should be done this way:

```
for letter in lowerCase[0]:
    newList.append([letter, i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is

```
newList.append([letter, i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your current code:

```
[newList.append(letter), newList.append(i)]
```

This line creates a list out of the output of those two method calls. You don't actually use the list, so you're basically doing:

```
newList.append(letter)
newList.append(i)
```

You want to append both elements at once inside of one iterable:

```
newList.append([letter, i])  
newList.append((letter, i))  # Tuples are faster to create, as they're immutable
```

Also, you usually don't need to create and increment an `i` variable by hand. Just use `enumerate`:

```
newList = []

for index, letter in enumerate(lowerCase[0], start=1):
    newList.append((letter, index))
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
newList = [(letter, index) for index, letter in enumerate(lowerCase[0], start=1)]
```